# Force external function to be const

Tags: c++, constants, mutable, const-correctness, const-cast

Here is my problem. I made a class with a member function declared as `const` that uses an external function that I cannot modify (declared in someone else's code) and that is not declared `const`. More precisely

#### Someone else's code

```cpp
class B {
public:
    void foo();
};
```

#### My code

```cpp
class A : public B {
public:
    void bar() const {
        this->foo();
    }
};
```

I know that for member data we can force const-correctness by using `mutable` or `const_cast`. How can I 'hack' `foo` such that my compiler understands that I would like to use it as if it was const even if it is not declared in someone else's code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Dont do that.
2. Don't do it like this:

Example:

```
class A : public B { 
public: 
    void bar() const { 
        const_cast<B*>(static_cast<const B*>(this))->foo();
    } 
};
```

**Edit:** The valid use-case for this is if:

1. The function `B::foo()` **doesn't modify state**, and **could have been declared `const`**, but...
2. The person who wrote `B::foo()` forgot to declare it const, and...
3. You can't change it because it will break something you don't control.

In theory this cannot happen but in practice it sometimes does.

The better answer, as the other answerers have correctly said, is to have `B::foo()` fixed, or to provide an alternate function which does the same thing **is** declared const.

Comment: I know it is not good coding. However I have to use someone else's code and I cannot change my source (files where `B` is declared). In my real code `A` inherits from another class `C` which has nothing to do with `B` so this cast is not possible although it should work in the simplified code I put in my original post. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: I am exactly in your valid use-case. I will try to get `B` fixed although it may not be possible, otherwise I will change all my design and not use const-correctness. Thanks for your detailed post.

Answer (score 3):

Just make your function non-const. That is the correct way to do it.

This makes clear that you will be modifying your state.

Comment: The code in my op is a simplified version of my real code. I need `bar` to be declared `const` for many reasons. I should have said that in my op.

Comment: All your reasons are invalid. If it isn't `const` don't make it `const`. Maybe you should overlook your design.

Comment: It is `const`. `bar` does not change the object as well but was not declared so and I cannot modify the class `B` since it is declared in someone else's code. I was just wondering if I could simply overcome this issue by using a hack. If not then I should indeed change my design.

Answer (score 1):

Either make `B::foo()` const, or make `A::bar()` non-const. One of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare bar() as follows:

```
void bar() const {
    B *that = (B *) this;
    that->foo();
}
```

Not sure about any unintended side affects.